# Lottie animation file not showing

Tags: javascript, html, lottie

I am trying to put a lottie animtion in my project, but it does not show up at all in the browser. I can inspect element and see the BODYMOVING LIBRARY in the head tag, and also the script below with the code. The file is sent to me in a zip file containing a .json file with the code for the animation,a svg for the photo not moving, a .html file with the demo.

I have imported the bodymoving library like this in the head of the project

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.7.8/lottie.min.js"></script>
```

And I am trying to use it in my html file like this

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <script>
       bodymovin.loadAnimation({
         container: document.getElementById('canvas'),
         renderer: 'canvas',
         loop: true,
         autoplay: true,
         path: 'data.json', // the .json file is in the same folder as the html
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web), you need to have a `div` that will hold your animation, so instead of
`<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>` try
`<div id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></div>`

For Example

```js
    bodymovin.loadAnimation({
         container: document.getElementById('canvas'),
         renderer: 'canvas',
         loop: true,
         autoplay: true,
         path: 'https://labs.nearpod.com/bodymovin/demo/markus/isometric/markus2.json'
     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.12.2/lottie.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```